# sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression not found

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, anaconda, lib

I have been trying to utilise mutual_info_regression method from sklearn, I have updated sklearn to latest build which is 0.24.1 and when I checked the source code inside my conda env path there is folder and files for feature_selection.mutual_info_regression, but when I try to import it in my Jupiter notebook it throws this error `ImportError: cannot import name 'mutual_info_regression' from 'sklearn.model_selection' (/opt/anaconda3/envs/<my_env>/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/__init__.py)`

I tried restarting kernel as well, but it is still not working, has anyone else faced this issue? Im using macOS 11.2.1 and conda 4.8.3 with Python3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

I just had to restart my terminal and then it started working for some reason.

I hope this helps anyone facing such problem in future

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

Check your sklearn version sklearn.model_selection is only available for version 0.18.1

Then try this in Jupyter Notebook cell
`from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression`

If any of the above doesn't work try these three steps
1- `pip uninstall sklearn`
2- `pip uninstall scikit-learn`
3- `pip install sklearn`